# SELECT 0 if NULL found - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, null

I have many tables of different product resources,

Unfortunately, `Quantity` column is of `Varchar` type.

Some of rows contain `null` values by default if `Quantity` was not entered during INSERT operation.

I want SELECT query to return `0` if quantity was `null`

```
SELECT CAST( quantity AS DECIMAL( 6, 2 ) ) 
FROM  `tablename`
```

But this still returns `NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST( quantity AS DECIMAL( 6, 2 ) ), 0) 
FROM  `tablename`
```

Comment: what if I have EMPTY value instead of `null` . will it return 0 as well?

Comment: Casting an empty string should make it's value 0

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CAST( COALESCE(quantity ,0) AS DECIMAL( 6, 2 ) )
FROM  `tablename`
```

Comment: what if I have EMPTY value instead of `null` . will it return 0 as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ifnull

```
SELECT ifnull(CAST( quantity AS DECIMAL( 6, 2 ) ), 0) from  your_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST( quantity AS DECIMAL( 6, 2 ) ), 0) 
FROM  `tablename`
```

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp